# How do I Remove box around lines of code?

Tags: visual-studio

I have noticed a white box around multiple lines of code when editing in Visual Studio 2017.  This is happening in Visual Basic code:

**Edit: Here's an image with the box I am asking about outlined in red.  It is a large box and I haven't been able to determine why it is there

Updated image

[image]

I've tried turning off 'Highlight current line' under Tools>Options>text Editor>General.  I didn't see any changes.  A 20 minute search on the net has not yielded any results either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: not sure what "White box" you are referring to. If you mean the one drawn around the line where the cursor is currently located it is just 1 line and should be controlled from that "Highlight current line" option. At least it does for me. Or are you referring to the thin line around the blue highlight in the lines of code you selected? If so I don't see that so it might be related to the color theme you've chosen for VS. May even be controllable via the Color Theme Editor plug-in, not sure.

Comment: I edited the image in my original post.  I haven't posted enough times to have it show in-line with my text but you can click the link to see it

Comment: Might have something to do with the break point and then editing? Remove the breakpoint and see if it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the identical problem.  I closed "Find" window in the upper right corner and the lines went away.  Presumably the lines outline scope of the Find function, or something similar...